# Problem processing php and uploading file, uploadify script

Tags: php, uploadify

I have a problem with php uploadify script.

I`m using single uploader, non multi.

Here is uploadify.php file which I edited:

```
<?php
// Callin
require_once("../../includes/functions.php");
connect_db();
check();
// If file exists
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
$tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
$targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);  //figures out the extension
$newFileName = md5($tempFile).'.'.$ext; //generates random filename, then adds the file extension
$targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $newFileName;
if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "gif" || $ext == "png") {
$imgsize = getimagesize($targetFile);
switch(strtolower(substr($targetFile, -3)))
    {
    case "jpg":
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFile);
    break;
    case "png":
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($targetFile);
    break;
    case "gif":
    $image = imagecreatefromgif($targetFile);
    break;
    default:
    exit;
    break;
    }
$width = 180;
$height = 135; // Don't need proportional
$src_w = $imgsize[0];
$src_h = $imgsize[1];

$picture = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagealphablending($picture, false);
imagesavealpha($picture, true);
$bool = imagecopyresampled($picture, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $src_w, $src_h);
if($bool)
{
switch(strtolower(substr($targetFile, -3)))
{
case "jpg":
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
$bool2 = imagejpeg($picture,$targetPath."../../galleries/vthumbs/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name'],80); // Two folders back to public_html, and /galleries/vthumbs/
break;
case "png":
header("Content-Type: image/png");
imagepng($picture,$targetPath."../../galleries/vthumbs/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']); // Two folders back to public_html, and /galleries/vthumbs/
break;
case "gif":
header("Content-Type: image/gif");
imagegif($picture,$targetPath."../../galleries/vthumbs/".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']); // Two folders back to public_html, and /galleries/vthumbs/
break;
}
}
imagedestroy($picture);
imagedestroy($image);
}
else {
// If extension isn't jpg or gif or png just move file
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
echo '0'; // Required to trigger onComplete function
}
else { // Required to trigger onComplete function
echo '1'; // For tests 
// mysql_query .........
}
?>
```

What I'm trying to make? 
I want to make uploader which upload videos and images files.
If it's image I want to make just thumbnail. i don't care about full image, if isn't image file, that must be video and just upload video.

I thnik that php code works fine, uploadify script don't have callback errors from uploadify.php, but when I change `if (!empty($_FILES))` to `if (empty($_FILES))` page shows me 0. By this, I thnik that php code is OK, and there is no errors.

But files isn't uploaded.  I checked for folder CHMODs and others. All is OK.
Script works with default uploadify.php code.
uploadify.php which I edited:

```
<?php
 if (!empty($_FILES)) {
 $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
 $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
 $targetFile = str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
 echo '0'; // Required to trigger onComplete function
 }
 else { // Required to trigger onComplete
 echo '1';
 }
 ?>
```

If need, I will paste javascript code with I calling uploadify.php, but I Thnik that is no nessesary, because script works with default uploadify.php and with edited uploadify.php no. 
All help is welcome...

Comment: Add your modifications one by one until it breaks. Then you will know which modification breaks the original code. By that point, it will either be very obvious what's wrong -- this is basic debugging! -- or you'll be able to post a really specific question here. SO doesn't like "debug my code plz".

Comment: I've already started with the classic debugging ... Of course not, PHP is concerned.
I've set up this pure coincidence that I predicted a catastrophic mistake

Comment: Set up a test form which calls the upload handler page directly so you can capture output and debug more readily without the javascript layer getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if (!empty($_FILES))` with `if (sizeof($_FILES) > 0)`